# This function converts a decimal to a hexadecimal, however it only prints two digits. How do I get it to print more?

Tags: python, hex, decimal

This only takes numbers up to 255 hence it only prints two digits. Why does it only print two digits? It looks like the while loop only runs once or something. It should run once or twice based on what I think. The hexadecimal for 5368 should be 14F8, the function gets close, but as you can see it only prints the 1 and 4, not the F or 8. Also, how can I get it to convert float numbers?

```
import math

def hexConvert(dec):

  while(math.floor(dec/16) > 0):
    x = ""
    rem = dec/16 - math.floor(dec/16)
    myHex = rem*16
    if myHex > 9 :
      if myHex == 10 :
        x += "A"

      if myHex == 11 :
        x += "B"

      if myHex == 12 :
        x += "C"

      if myHex == 13 :
        x += "D"

      if myHex == 14 :
        x += "E"

      if myHex == 15 :
        x += "F"

    else :
      myHex = str(int(myHex))
      x += myHex  
    dec = math.floor(dec/16)

  remainder = dec/16 - math.floor(dec/16)
  myHex2 = remainder*16
  if myHex2 > 9 :
    if myHex2 == 10 :
      x += "A"

    if myHex2 == 11 :
      x += "B"

    if myHex2 == 12 :
      x += "C"

    if myHex2 == 13 :
      x += "D"

    if myHex2 == 14 :
      x += "E"

    if myHex2 == 15 :
      x += "F"

  else :
    myHex2 = str(int(myHex2))
    x += str(myHex2)  

  x = x[::-1]
  print ("Hex: " + x)

hexConvert(5368)
```

Comment: And I do know about the Hex command but can someone build off this code and get it to run the right amount of times for any number?

Comment: You need to add a loop that will produce the number of digits you need.

Comment: You may want to look into the modulus command as well as the floor division command. I think it could clean up your code a bit.

Comment: But different numbers produce different numbers of digits. What is the modulus command?

Comment: use divmod :) is the easiest probably

Comment: well really using `hex` is the easiest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the assignment of `x` outside of your while loop. Define x using `x = ""` immediately after the function definition, then delete the redefinition. The first four lines should read:

```
import math

def hexConvert(dec):
  x = ""
  while(math.floor(dec/16) > 0):
    rem = dec/16 - math.floor(dec/16)
```

As of right now, you're clearing out the X value every two digits, causing you to lose the F8 that should be at the end.

Comment: Additionally, look into the modulus command as well as the floor division command. [The documentation for both can be found here.](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) This should help clean up your code considerably!